# How do i add more than 2 Template in a MAP c++?

Tags: c++, dictionary

Currently I'm trying to implement a map data structure to solve my problem, but I could only add two templates to one map. For example

```
map<string, int> data;
```

If I want to add more than two, it won't work, I will get all sorts of memory and map semantic errors, like

```
Memory

1) type allocator_type aka int cannot be used  prior to '::'


Map

1)  rebind_alloc following 'template' keyword does not refer to a 
template

2) Multiple overloads of 'map' instantiate to the same signature 'void(const)
```

Here's the code

```
    void Teacher::modifyScore(string newName, int newEnglish, int newMath, int newBio) {

    // Holds file data
    map<string, int, int, int> data;

    // Read file and fill data map
    ifstream studentRec("StudentRecord.txt");
    string line;

    while (getline(studentRec, line))
    {
        string name;
        int english;
        int math;
        int bio;
        stringstream ss(line);
        ss >> name >> english >> math >> bio;
        data[name] = english;
        data[name] = math;
        data[name] = bio;
    }

    studentRec.close();

    // Print data
    for (auto& entry : data)
    {
        cout << entry.first << " " << entry.second << endl;
    }
    // Modify data
    if(data[newEnglish] != 0) {
        data[newName] = newEnglish;
    }

    if(data[newMath] != 0) {
        data[newName] = newMath;
    }

    if(data[newBio] != 0) {
        data[newName] = newBio;
    }

//    if(data[newChemical] != 0) {
//        data[newName] = newChemical;
//    }

    // Open same file for output, overwrite existing data
    ofstream ofs("StudentRecord.txt");
    for (auto& entry : data)
    {
        ofs << entry.first << setw(10) << entry.second << setw(10) << entry.third << setw(10) << entry.fourth << endl;
    }
    ofs.close();

}
```

It will only work with only 2 templates.

Edited: How do i ofstream each data ?

```
for (const auto& entry : data)
    {
        tie(newEnglish, newBio, newMath) = entry.second;


        of << entry.first << setw(10) << ?? << setw(10) << ?? << setw(10) <<  ?? << endl;

    }
```

Comment: please learn proper terminology. "adding templates to a map" is complete nonsense. What you want to do is **instantiate the map class template with type parameters where the value type is a compound type.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to use is a tuple http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple

The std::map can only store 2 parameters: keytype and datatype, conceptually, you need a data type which stores multiple data types.

Your map would become something like

```
std::map<std::string, std::tuple<int, int, int>> data;
```

For tuple usage, please refer to the linked documentation

EDIT:
To add a new value, you would use

```
int a, b, c;
...
data["Batman"] = std::make_tuple(a, b, c);
```

EDIT2:
Inside the while loop, the code

```
    data[name] = english;
    data[name] = math;
    data[name] = bio;
```

would become

```
    data[name] = std::make_tuple(english, math, bio);
```

EDIT3
To access the tuple data, you need to use std::tie

```
int english, bio, math; 
std::tie(english, bio, math) = data["batman"];
```

EDIT4
Minimal sample for access on tuple data inside a for loop iterating over a map

```
#include <map>
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::tuple<int, int, int>> data;

    for (const auto& entry : data)
    {
        int a, b, c;
        std::tie(a, b, c) = entry.second;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT5
The std::tie function extracts the tuple data into the supplied variables.

Your code

```
tie(newEnglish, newBio, newMath) = entry.second;
of << entry.first << setw(10) << ?? << setw(10) << ?? << setw(10) <<  ?? << endl;
```

would become

```
tie(newEnglish, newBio, newMath) = entry.second;
of << entry.first << setw(10) << newEnglish << setw(10) << newBio << setw(10) <<  newMath << endl;
```

Comment: How do i enter a data for example, entry.first, entry.second[0]?

Comment: and in the while loop, what should I put? data[name] = ??

Comment: How do i outstream it? &entry.second[?] .

Comment: I tried using **&get<0>(entry)** but it still showing memory allocation instead of the actual value

Comment: One last thing, how do i do tie in a for-loop?

Comment: There should be no special syntax required, just put a for loop around the sample code. Ill add some code to clarify

Comment: can you show a sample code? so I could accept your answer, thank you so much for being patient.

Comment: check my edited question, at the end, I'm really confused of how to of stream it. Really sorry for asking so many questions

Comment: Whereas `std::tuple` works, using a `struct` would allow to give semantic to the different `int`. and would have directly something like`entry.second.English`